# How to add a eventListener for each post (without using jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a code where the user can fetch user posts in a list of post titles. If the user clicks on a post title then there should show up a new div box with more information. The posts are fetched with php and the post description will fetched by AJAX. (later i will fetch the posts also with  AJAX)

**My Problem:** Only the first post title works and by clicking it, all post description show up in 1 div box. I think I need an array, and was trying it with no success.

**What It Should Do:** For example by clicking on title: 2, only the description of post 2 should show up. 
And remember, the post title list is dynamic and are fetched data from database.

Here is my code:

## INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XY</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          echo "<div class='img_title'><button id='img_descr'><a>Title: <b>".$row['img_title']."</b></a></button></div>";
      }
    ?>
    <div id="descrs"></div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('img_descr').addEventListener('click', loadDescr);

      function loadDescr(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'ajax.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function(){
          if(this.status == 200){
            var descrs = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            var output = '';

            for(var i in descrs){
              output += '<ul>' +
                '<li class="ajax_img_descr">ID: '+descrs[i].img_descr+'</li>' +
                '</ul>';
            }
            document.getElementById('descrs').innerHTML = output;
          }
        }
        xhr.send();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## AJAX.PHP

```
<?php
// Create Connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'xy');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM images';
// Get Result
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// Fetch Data
$users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($users);
?>
```

## Database Structure/Content:

1. Create a database called "xy"
2. Create a table called "images":

   ```
   CREATE TABLE images (
       img_id int(11) not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
       img_file varchar(250) not null,
       img_title text(50) not null,
       img_descr varchar(250) not null
   );
   ```
3. Insert data to database:

   ```
   INSERT INTO images (img_title, img_descr) VALUES ('Golden Retriever', 'UK:DFYDFBAERSDFBYDFBYDFydfbydfBaeydfb1311y');
   INSERT INTO images (img_title, img_descr) VALUES ('Appenzeller Sennenhund', 'Swiss:erydfydfbrehaydydfbydfydbaerydf2ydfb');
   INSERT INTO images (img_title, img_descr) VALUES ('German Shepard', 'Germany:ydf3d1fby3df1by3dfb6ydfb31ydf31ydf');
   INSERT INTO images (img_title, img_descr) VALUES ('Alaskan Klee Kai', 'USA:f3ngxfgxfgnxfxfgnxfg3xf31gnxfgner6ae13')
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are using same ID `img_descr` for all buttons.** That's why it will work for the first button's event only and not for others.

Try using the class for those buttons or unique ids. Below is the example of using a common class for those buttons.
`document.querySelectorAll` will return all buttons with class "img_descr" as NodeList(DOM Node List) which is an array kind, you can iterate over it using the loop.You can use CSS Selectors .(dot) class / # for (id) here.

Here is the example, it is working on my pc. hope it works on yours too!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XY</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
       $db     = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
       $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          // changed <button id='img_descr'> to <button class='img_descr'>
          echo "<div class='img_title'><button class='img_descr'><a>Title: <b>" . $row['img_title'] . "</b></a></button></div>";
       }
     ?>
     <div id="descrs"></div>
     <script>
       // Get the buttons (NodeList)
       var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.img_descr"); 
       console.log(buttons); // debugging in JS!! press F12, see console tab!

       for(var x=0; x < buttons.length; x++) {
         buttons[x].addEventListener('click', loadDescr);
       }

       // getElementById returns only one element with the id passed as input
       // which is the first found node with the id in the DOM.
       // document.getElementById('img_descr').addEventListener('click', loadDescr);

     function loadDescr(e) {
        // here e is the event and you can get the source of the event(button) by
        // e.target target. Here target would be the button that you clicked.
        console.log(e.target.innerHTML); // use console.log() very often in JS code!
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'ajax.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
           if (this.status == 200) {
             var descrs = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

             var output = '';

             for (var i in descrs) {
               output += '<ul>' +
                   '<li class="ajax_img_descr">ID: ' + descrs[i].img_descr + '</li>' +  '</ul>';
             }
             document.getElementById('descrs').innerHTML = output;
         }
       }
       xhr.send();
     }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Q1: **Do I have to work with the "img_id" to achieve that or is there a other to do this? Do you want, that I start a new question for this?**

Ans1: *ID is something that should always be unique for all the elements. Via ID you can uniquely identify the Node in the DOM. You can use the `img_id` from DB which is primary key.*

Q2: **every description are getting displayed all together by clicking any button. What i need is: 
    Click title 1 --> get descr 1, 
    click title 2 --> get descr 2 and so on and so forth and the title list are getting loaded dynamically**

Ans2: *You can do this using this way, though there are multiple ways to do this:*

```
// 1.1 PHP Change
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  // changed <button id='img_descr'> to <button class='img_descr' id=row's id column>
  echo "<div class='img_title'><button class='img_descr' id="$row['id']"><a>Title: <b>" . $row['img_title'] . "</b></a></button></div>";
}
```

---

```
// 1.2 JS change
function loadDescr(e) {
     ...
     console.log(e.target.innerHTML); // use console.log() very often in JS code!
     let id = e.target.getAttribute('id'); // get the ID of element, e.target.id also does the same 
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', 'ajax.php?img='+id, true); // append the id in query
     ...
 }
```

---

```
// 1.3 PHP ajax.php change

// check if the query has id passed
if (isset($_GET['img'])) {
    $id = $_GET['img'];
    // change the query to find by id
    $query = "SELECT * from images where img_id=$id";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * from images";
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// Fetch Data
$users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($users);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: as soon i use a class instead of an id, then nothing getting displayed, i also used document.getElementsByClassName('descrs').innerHTML = output; instead of document.getElementById('descrs').innerHTML = output;

Comment: and do i have to use: var buttons; for(var ...) { buttons[x]...);   ...and then the rest of my JS code here?}

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i'm a step further, but i still have the problem, that every description are getting displayed all together by clicking any button. What i need is: Click title 1 --> get descr 1, click title 2 --> get descr 2 and so on and so forth and the title list are getting loaded dynamically.

Comment: Do I have to work with the "img_id" to achieve that or is there a other to do this? Do you want, that I start a new question for this?

Comment: I found a solution for my problem and accepted your answer for this question! thank you!